# Windows Task Scheduler DLL Caching Issue?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I'm having an issue where I can concisely prove that task scheduler is running an old version of a supporting DLL my executable uses.

Here's what I have:
A C# console app that just calls into a manager function in a class library (more specifically, it's the data access layer). That class library imports yet another class library for "core" functions shared across multiple applications.

If I run the application from windows explorer, it runs fine.

When it gets run from the task scheduler, it appears to run at least a version back. Literally three core functions are functioning as they did a version back ago.

Comment: what version of window task scheduler you are using ?

Comment: I have this issue with Windows Server 2008 R2 And Windows 7 Professional. I haven't tried any other versions of Windows, but it needs to work on one of these operating systems.

Comment: Do you have anything installed in the GAC?

Comment: I didn't intentionally install anything into the GAC. I checked C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly and C:\Windows\Assembly for my DLLs and they are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way this can happen in Windows. Turns out another server that I wasn't aware of had these scheduled tasks scheduled to happen one minute before my task would execute, and this server wasn't running the latest version of the application.

So, if this happens to you: check ALL servers that you are hosting before going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by running an old version of supporting DLL my executable uses.

If your C# Console is using Microsoft Task Scheduler COM there are different version of modal however you can refer the [Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: No, I'm using the task scheduler directly.

I tried logging the Application Version of the manager class using an out parameter and it always says "1.0.0.0", despite upping the version number

Comment: I believe the 1.0.0 is the version of your manager class assembly. What indeed is your problem, why are you suspect it run at least a version back?

Comment: My data access layer has functionality of a version back.

Specifically, I changed it from writing to the file system (via UNC path, which was problematic) to posting to an API, I changed a ternary operator around so it should pick up empty subject lines and convert them to "no subject", and I also added a new field in the database that I am setting in the data access layer. which is always getting it's default value. None of these changes appear to be apparent when task scheduler runs the executable.

But when I run it via Windows Explorer, it runs fine.

Comment: how about you set up a new schedule task and see if it is working ?

Comment: I deleted and re-added the task, it worked the first time on schedule, but after it ran again on schedule it went back to having the same problem.

Comment: it seem like the window schedule is working fine and somehow your application layer (data access and other dlls) you using preventing it refresh the changed. You might need to creating logging on the application to track down the problem.

Comment: It does log exceptions and it logs each "email account" it processes in the main executable. What would I log in the data access layer, and how would that help me track down the problem?

Comment: Turns out there was another server running the application.